# D3js v4 get month and year

Tags: d3.js

I made a chart on d3js and on my Xaxis I have some months to show. My time parsing function `d3.timeParse("%Y-%m")` returns me only months like 'January , February'.

But I would like to get these months in this format : 'Jan-2019, Feb-2019'. What can I do pls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the abbreviated month(`%b`) specifier string to get the abbreviated/shortform month names.

If you want the dates to be formatted as Jan-2019, and Feb-2019, you can do the following:

```js
const formatMonth = d3.timeFormat('%b-%Y');
const date = new Date(2014, 1, 1); 

console.log(formatMonth(date));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

You may read find the supported specifier formats for d3.timeParse over [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format#locale_format).